# ¿Cómo sacar el valor Mínimo de una Columna?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Cómo sacar el valor mínimo de una columna sin usar una subconsulta, tengo esta tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE ARTICULO
(
    CODIGO NUMBER,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(100),
    PRECIO FLOAT,
    FABRICANTE NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_ARTICULO" PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO) ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_ARTICULO_FABRICANTE" FOREIGN KEY (FABRICANTE) REFERENCES FABRICANTE(CODIGO) ENABLE,

);


INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (1,'Mouse', 100.99,1);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (2,'Teclado', 200.50,1);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (3,'Bocinas', 150.50,2);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (4,'Computadora', 300.50,3);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (5,'MausePAD', 20.50,2);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (6,'Telefono', 5000.50,1);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (7,'SmartPhone', 4000.50,4);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (8,'Audifonos', 800.50,1);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (9,'Television', 700.50,5);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (10,'Radio', 600.50,6);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (11,'PS4 2017', 8000.50,7);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (12,'Monitor', 1000.50,8);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (13,'Monitor Touch', 2000.50,2);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (14,'Teclado Gamer', 2050.50,3);
INSERT INTO ARTICULO VALUES (15,'Mouse Gamer', 2080.50,10);
```

habrá alguna forma de obtener el nombre y precio del articulo mas barato.

La query con una subconsulta:

```
    SELECT NOMBRE, PRECIO 
FROM ARTICULO WHERE PRECIO=(SELECT MIN(PRECIO) FROM ARTICULO);
```

¿Cómo puedo convertirlo a uno sin usar la subconsulta usando `MIN()`?

Pensé en:

```
SELECT NOMBRE,PRECIO
FROM ARTICULO
GROUP BY NOMBRE,PRECIO
HAVING PRECIO=MIN(PRECIO);
```

Comment: Lamentablemente en versiones anteriores a la 12c, no se puede resolver sin usar subconsultas. ¿Podrías confirmarnos que versión estas usando?

Comment: la version es 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes simplemente ordenar por precio y seleccionar solo un valor (como está ordenado, será el más barato):

```
SELECT NOMBRE, PRECIO FROM ARTICULO ORDER BY PRECIO ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: no lo había pensado de esta forma gracias.

Comment: `LIMIT` según entiendo es una clausula de Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

¿No alcanzaría con usar?

- Seleccionar las columnas deseadas `NOMBRE` y `PRECIO`
- Hacer un ordedamiento ascendente por la columna `PRECIO`
- Limitar a 1 los registros obtenidos

De tal modo que tu consulta luciera así:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, PRECIO FROM ARTICULO
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY PRECIO ASC;
```

**Edito**

Realicé algunas pruebas con el primer comando y no resultaron exitosas, por eso seguí buscando y encontré [rownum](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm)